# Build success, no errors but white screen

Tags: reactjs, cordova

I have a react application generating with create-react-app that I would like to transform into a hybrid app thanks to cordova. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/johnkmzhou/cordova-create-react-app) for configuration. everything seems to be going well, the build is done as it should be and the app runs through the emulator but whether it's on android or iOS the only thing I see is a white screen

I initialized a new react app in that I configured to use with cordova, it works very well, I transposed this configuration to my existing app. 
My app uses redux and react-router as a particular library.

I don't think it's a Policy issue.

builded index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#008000">
  <meta name="title" content="Lunchs du Bureau">
  <meta name="description" content="Partager votre repas avec vos collègues de bureau.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="lunch, repas, dejeuner">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://staging.lunchsdubureau.com" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="lunch-seo.jpg" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, nofollow">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="language" content="French">
  <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-icon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yesteryear|Raleway:400,700|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
  <script>var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || []; OneSignal.push(function () { OneSignal.init({ appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx", autoResubscribe: !0, notifyButton: { enable: !1 } }), OneSignal.showNativePrompt() })</script>
  <title>Lunchs du Bureau</title>
  <link href="./static/css/main.d76f0357.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>!function (l) { function e(e) { for (var r, t, n = e[0], o = e[1], u = e[2], f = 0, i = []; f < n.length; f++)t = n[f], p[t] && i.push(p[t][0]), p[t] = 0; for (r in o) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (l[r] = o[r]); for (s && s(e); i.length;)i.shift()(); return c.push.apply(c, u || []), a() } function a() { for (var e, r = 0; r < c.length; r++) { for (var t = c[r], n = !0, o = 1; o < t.length; o++) { var u = t[o]; 0 !== p[u] && (n = !1) } n && (c.splice(r--, 1), e = f(f.s = t[0])) } return e } var t = {}, p = { 1: 0 }, c = []; function f(e) { if (t[e]) return t[e].exports; var r = t[e] = { i: e, l: !1, exports: {} }; return l[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, f), r.l = !0, r.exports } f.m = l, f.c = t, f.d = function (e, r, t) { f.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, { enumerable: !0, get: t }) }, f.r = function (e) { "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 }) }, f.t = function (r, e) { if (1 & e && (r = f(r)), 8 & e) return r; if (4 & e && "object" == typeof r && r && r.__esModule) return r; var t = Object.create(null); if (f.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: r }), 2 & e && "string" != typeof r) for (var n in r) f.d(t, n, function (e) { return r[e] }.bind(null, n)); return t }, f.n = function (e) { var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () { return e.default } : function () { return e }; return f.d(r, "a", r), r }, f.o = function (e, r) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r) }, f.p = "./"; var r = window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || [], n = r.push.bind(r); r.push = e, r = r.slice(); for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++)e(r[o]); var s = n; a() }([])</script>
  <script src="./static/js/2.e49e8dbb.chunk.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/js/main.e081436f.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

config.xml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

[image: scrrenshot]

Comment: It works fine on browser platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
"homepage": "./"
```

to your `package.json`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed, the problem came from there.

I have been under Ionic-Capacitor since then which is much easier to use

Comment: @eth3rnit3 but did you implement codepush in it ?

Comment: Would be great if you guys could precise if it's needed in the react or cordova package.json :)